# Self-built LibreOffice runs but nothing is visible

Tags: linux, libreoffice

I have followed the instructions at https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/Development/BuildingOnLinux to build LibreOffice on Ubuntu 16.10. When it finished the `make` step I ran `instdir/program/soffice --writer` and the splash screen appeared for a few seconds then disappeared, but no main window appeared in its place. I can see that the `soffice.bin` process is running, in System Monitor, but I can't use the application. Have I done something wrong? I have already tried `git pull` and repeating `make`, and restarting the system, but it hasn't made any difference.

Comment: This was a bug introduced a few days ago and fixed Sunday afternoon affecting the gtk3 backend on X11. Any other backend or using wayland was fine. Please update your source code and rebuild.

Comment: Thanks, that has worked. Looks like it was this: https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=106772